# Redirect traffic from tun0 to eth0:0

Tags: iptables, openvpn

Есть сервер openvpn, настроенный с помощью https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install с 2 интерфейсами eth0 и eth0:0. Подключение к серверу осуществляется через eth0, а исходящий трафик должен идти с eth0:0. Что мне нужно изменить в моей конфигурации /etc/iptables/add-openvpn-rules.sh, чтобы выполнить задачу?

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0:0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i eth0:0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i tun0 -o eth0:0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: it is Russian language segment. Please, use English one or translate to Russian.

Answer (score 1):

eth0:0 не существует. Это тот же eth0. Маскарад работает на pref source вмашруте. Используй SNAT.